# Angular2 global configuration file

Tags: javascript, angular

I've got an Angular2 project with this structure :

```
client/ // Angular2 client
    app/
        app.component.ts
        ...
    main.ts
    ...
server/ // API
    server.js
config/ // config files
    webpack.config.js
    ...
```

I'd like to have all constants and parameters of the Angular2 app (like the url to the API...) in the config directory, with all other config files.
How can I perform it in Angular2 ? As the config folder is outside the client folder, is it a good practice to import something that is outside, with many "../../../" ?

Also I wanted to use dependency injection, but is there anything less heavy ?
And how can I avoid to import manually the file in each component/module I want to use it ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

What I used is probably the not best approach but, I'm using webpack to inject global variables with the DefinePlugin plugin:

I use the .env file on root, to store the variables, I have a .env.TST, .env.PRD and replace it with deployment script

**webpack.common.js**

```
var preEnv = require('../.env');
var envVars = {};
for(var propertyName in preEnv) {
  envVars[propertyName] = '"'+preEnv[propertyName]+'"';
}
```

...

```
plugins: [
new webpack.DefinePlugin(
       envVars 
    )
]
```

...

Example **.env** file

```
module.exports = {
    "APIURL": "https://localhost/MyAPI/",
    "PUBLIC_URL": "https://localhost:3000/",
    "BASE_PATH": "/"
    "ENV": "dev"
}
```

And you will have `APIURL` as a global variable

Additionaly I added a file into the typings, to prevent warnings:

**typings/typings.d.ts**

```
declare var APIURL: string;
declare var PUBLIC_URL: string;
declare var ENV: string;
declare var BASE_PATH: string;
```

I hope it helps to someone

Answer (score 0):

1. Inside you package.json you can write an npm script for every environment. that you are going to support:

```js
"scripts": {
    "build:dev": "webpack --config config/webpack.dev.js",
     "build:prod": "webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js"
}
```

2. Then in every config/webpack.xxxx.dev script you can declare global variables using Webpack **DefinePlugin** || **ExtendedDefinePlugin**. It  is **vital to understand** that this plugin allows you to have your global server-side node.js variables, become available as global client-side .js variables.

This is how your webpack.dev.js might look like

```js
 new DefinePlugin({
   'ENV': JSON.stringify('Development'),
   'URL': JSON.stringify('http://...')      
 })
```

...

This is how your webpack.prod.js might look like

```js
 new DefinePlugin({
   'ENV': JSON.stringify('Prod'),
   'URL': JSON.stringify('http://...')      
 })
```

...

3. Finally is your .ts files you can then write

   declare var URL: string; //keeps the compiler happy

   let configUrl: string = URL;

link to example github project: [ng2a.frontend](https://github.com/HNeukermans/Ng2a.Frontend)